# How can I solve "The procedure entry point @testbpl_common@initialization$qqrv could not be located in the dynamic library test.bpl"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm facing a trouble when executing delphi project.(on Delphi7)
It succeeded compiling but fails executing at LoadPackage(loaderpath) and the message looks like below.

"The procedure entry point @testbpl_common@initialization$qqrv could not be located in the dynamic library test.bpl"

The message which really isn't the one I got on my computer but I found it on the link having same trouble below.
I tried the solution on the page, but still can't solve mine.

[Procedure Entry Point](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=174106)

Please let me know other solution or the way of debug this kind of issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this problem.
The problem was %PATH% on my computer.

Since there is duplicated executable files on my computer, delphi loaded unexpected dll while executing.
So I fixed %PATH% to solve this problem.

The way I find out this problem is below.

1. Use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to check list of dll to find which one of them is loaded.(I found some of them is on the wrong place(wrong version).)
2. Use 'where xxx.dll' command on cmd.exe to check %PATH% of that dll.
3. Renamed that path and try to execute that project on delphi to check it fails because some of dll couldn't loaded.
4. I changed %PATH% to proper place and solved this problem.

Comment: The issue might also be caused if you have multiple Delphi IDEs installed but removing the Users\Public\Documents\Rad Studio\xx\Bpl from the environment variable will be complained about by the IDE. So appending the version suffix to packages is required